# Assign value of every int in file to string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm very lost with the idea of being able to read a file in java with a scanner. I want to put into a string every int from a txt file ( the ints are on multiple lines ), but I can't seem to make it work.

```
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        String fileStr = "";

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            fileStr += Integer.toString(sc.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println(fileStr);
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792069/get-int-from-text-file-and-set-it-to-variable?

Answer (score 0):

you can try parsing an string into int, if it works it means that you have an int in the file. then you can add it to a string

something like this

```
int number;
try {
   number = Integer.toString(sc.nextInt());
   fileStr += number;
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
  fileStr += '';
}
```